# Installing .air without admin rights?

Tags: adobe, air

i would like to distribute an Adobe Air App. But most enterprise companies doen't allow the installation of new apps.

Is there any workaround to **make an Air App installable to as many users as possible?**

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not I think. I have to install my application as Administrator and then it works fine. But I have got the same issue when auto update is running...

Damien

Comment: That's correct. I've been researching this same problem, and there is no way around it unless you use Captive Runtime (as pointed out by Mat) to create a standalone installation.

Answer (score 0):

Now with AIR 3.0 you can pack the captive runtime together with the air app.

and this is an article that describes a technique to create an AIR app that can be updated without admin rights: http://www.mabulous.net/air-applications-that-can-be-updated-without-requiring-admin-rights

Comment: Yeah that article is great but my app has crazy sizes and a huge border. It does not even look like the resolution inside that sprite used as a launcher is correct. Its like the launched app is scaled. What if I installed the .air in the desktop and overwrited the META-INf and swf with the unpacked update?

Comment: Correction! I had to set stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
   stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
   stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;Now it looks like it works.